# Whether jersey’s concrete class org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig can be used along with javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder

Tags: java, cxf, jersey-client

I have question related to **cxf-rt-rs-client-3.3.1.**

Background : 
I am working on legacy application which uses jersey-client-2.7 for http requests, since jersey-client-2.7 does not support HTTP PATCH method,we are using cxf-rt-rs-client-3.3.1.

And HTTP PATCH started to work without any changes after inclusion of  cxf-rt-rs-client-3.3.1.jar in our class path along with its dependencies.

Reason :

javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.java has following piece of code

```
String serviceId = "META-INF/services/“ + factoryId;
```

javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.java has following piece of code

```
Object delegate = FactoryFinder.find("javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder", "org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder");
```

Since  cxf-rt-rs-client-3.3.1 in class path along with jersey-client-2.7, the precedence is given to cxf-rt-rs-client-3.3.1.

And we are using passing org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig to javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder

Code Snippet :

```
  ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
  clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.SSL_CONFIG, sslConfigurator);
  ConnectorProvider connectorProvider = new ApacheConnectorProvider();
  clientConfig.connectorProvider(connectorProvider);

  verifyingClient = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
      .withConfig(clientConfig).build();
```

Question :

Whether jersey’s concrete class  org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig can be used along with javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder ?

Please revert back at your earliest convenience.

Thanks

Comment: My guess is only for (CXF specific) properties. If you are expecting CXF client to use a different connector based on Jersey's specific configuration class, I highly doubt it. It is up to the implementation of the client what they decide to do with the Configuration.